# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate doesn't work with Stripe on everything else it works without side effects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am having issue with adding balance to user, I have stripe testing checkout and after processing data and checking if it's correct. After wanting to add balance to user instead
of adding for example 1+2=3 what happens is I get 1+2=12 like it's appending numbers.

This is function used for adding balance it's used in other functions, but when I added stripe it just started to append numbers.

```js
Users.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
  Users.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email: email },
    { balance: user.balance + amount }
  ).then(result => {
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Success" });
  });
});
```

I checked the amount, amount is still same as it comes from front end it's never changed or touched from original state.

Comment: Check your types. If either the balance or amount is stored as a string, the result will be 12. The likely culprit is that user.balance is defined as a string in your model.

Comment: Can you post the code for your UserSchema? Additionally what is the input value of `amount`, perhaps you forgot to convert it to an Integer? Have you tried `parseInt(amount)`. This seems like a typical issue of having wrong data types, for example "1" (string) + 1 (int) will always equal "11", not 2 (int).

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I stored it in a React state as a number and input type is number, but it got converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of the `balance` or `amount` or both are of type string, hence its being concatenated instead of addition, do `parseInt(user.balance) + parseInt(amount)` to make sure it's not string

Also, you can achieve what you want using single query by setting values using `$inc` operator like below, just make sure balance in your `User` model is of type `Number`

```
Users.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email: email }, 
    { $inc: {
         balance: amount
        }
    })
    .then(
        result => {
           return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success' }
    );
```

This will increment `balance` whatever values is there inside balance with `amount`

Comment: For some reason stripe converted it into string even tough stripe was never supposed to change it, I will accept your answer. It's fixed now by parseinting amount.